# Как закрыть для доступа IP адрес сервера?

Tags: nginx

Есть сервер. На сервере развернут проект, который доступен по домену.

Nginx конфигурация:

```
upstream app {
    server unix:/home/user/app/socket.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /home/user/app/public;

    # ...
}
```

Проблема в том, что сайт доступен и по IP адресу.

Как запретить (или лучше перенаправить) с IP адреса на домен подскажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

Добавить сервер по умолчанию (который будет принимать запросы к неизвестным доменам, в том числе IP-адрес), и в нём прописать всё что вам надо

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    # Остальные нужные вам listen (https, ipv6) аналогично

    server_name _;  # Пустышка, чтобы не привязывать сервер ни к какому домену

    location / {
        return 302 http://вашсайт.рф/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Делает кучу редиректов при переходе по домену, потом браузер блочит за это.

Comment: @Colibri значит `вашсайт.рф` у вас неправильно настроен, проверьте тамошний `server_name`

Comment: Ну я же выложил основную часть конфига. Что не так с ним?

Comment: Не знаю, с ним всё в порядке, но если у вас уходит в вечный редирект, значит вы накосячили с `server_name` в реальном конфиге